# WPF Popup PlacementTarget=0,0 of ToggleButton

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, togglebutton

I have a popup that appears when I click a togglebutton like so.

```
<ToggleButton  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Template="{StaticResource MyToggleButton}" Name="MyToggleButton" />
<Popup Name="MyPopUp"  IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=MyToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyToggleButton}" Placement="Center">
// blah blah
</Popup>
```

How can I get the popup to appear at the 0,0 position of my toggle button? (The top left of my popup is the same position as the top left of the toggle button)

I have tried using PlacementTarget and can get it to appear left/right/top/botton but now exactly over the top of the ToggleButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: Set `Placement` to `Relative`, and leave `Popup.VerticalOffset` and `Popup.HorizontalOffset` both at their default value of 0.

```
<Popup 
    Name="MyPopUp"  
    IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=MyToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}" 
    StaysOpen="False"  
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyToggleButton}" 
    Placement="Relative"
    >
```

Out of curiosity, are you doing this to prevent the user from clicking on the `ToggleButton` while the popup is open?